Is it possible to restore a manifold knowing only its metric?
Is it possible to restore a Riemannian manifold (up to isomorphism, that is homeomorphisms (preserving Riemannian dot-products) of all "charts" that the two manifolds could be split into, for at least one atlas for each of the two manifolds compared) knowing only its metric (and that it's a Riemannian manifold)?
Note that Riemannian here is important, because "regular" (non-Riemannian) manifolds don't have a "canonical" metric.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The answer is yes. It is covered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45154/riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-metric. The paper in which it is shown that the metric induced by the Riemannian metric is enough to reconstruct the Riemannian structure is "ON THE DIFFERENTIABILITY OF ISOMETRIES" by Richard S. Palais (see for example this link https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-04/S0002-9939-1957-0088000-X/S0002-9939-1957-0088000-X.pdf).

The answer is yes. It is covered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45154/riemannian-metric-induced-by-a-metric. The paper in which it is shown that the metric induced by the Riemannian metric is enough to reconstruct the Riemannian structure is "On the differentiability of isometries" by Richard S. Palais (see for example this link https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-04/S0002-9939-1957-0088000-X/S0002-9939-1957-0088000-X.pdf).
If we would give ourselves a bit more structure, then it becomes easier to reconstruct the Riemannian metric. Namely, if we start from a $C^1$ manifold and the metric induced by a Riemannian metric, then we can express the Riemannian metric in terms of the induced metric as explained in this answer Riemannian metric induced by metric.
